# Replicate EAV data model as Conventional data model and use Conventional model for querying in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, etl, database-replication

We have an EAV database model built on SQL Server 2008. Knew about the performance problems with EAV before choosing EAV (benefits from EAV outweighed performance problems).

To reduce performance impact of SQL Joins, we used Indexed views, Pivoting, Querying in Batch etc, and performance improved but not up to the mark.

Now, trying to use, SQL Server replication and ETL to improve the SELECT queries performance.

Does anybody have good source of information on how to implement/convert EAV database to conventional database (using ETL or any other way) for only querying purpose and use replication(or any other way) to update the conventional database from EAV?

Or is there any other mechanism to achieve the desired behaviour?